# Get one facebook post by ID

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Then I rty to get post I receive error:

```
{
  "error": {
  "message": "Unsupported get request.",
  "type": "GraphMethodException",
  "code": 100
 }
}
```

And the request:
    https://graph.facebook.com/100002485262717_622325677860269?access_token=*token*&appsecret_proof=*proof*

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I undersand. I should remove userId from request